# Showing moving clouds over still sky

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am totally new to Cocos2D and want to develop a game...right now i am working on giving initial look and feel to the game...I need to show a blue sky as background and moving clouds,birds etc above it...please suggest me the best approach for this...?

Comment: your question is too general. better break it into smaller questions, for example in the form of "how do I do A?", "after I do B, do I need to do C or D?" etc so that people here can approach your questions better. and it's best if you can post some code that you have worked on so that we don't feel as if you are trying to make us code for you.

Answer (score 0):

create you scene like this, it will create a sky in background and the you have clouds and above them all there are birds (i just didn't set ther positions):

```
CCSprite* sky=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sky.png"]
CCSprite*birds[10];
CCSprite*clouds[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    birds[i] = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bird.png"];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    clouds[i] = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"cloud.png"];

[self addChild:sky z:-1];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    [self addChild:birds[i] z:1];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    [self addChild:clouds[i] z:0];
```